# What is Alteryx right outer self join equal to, in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, alteryx

[I am trying to migrate the alteryx workflow in pyspark dataframes, as part of which I came across this right outer self join on different columns (ph_id_1 and ph_id_2), while doing the same in pyspark, i am not getting the correct output, have tried Anti, left anti join. All are giving the same result. Any suggestion how to do it in pyspark way or sql way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxNy.png)

Tried:

```
df_new = df_1.join(df_2,[df_1['ph_id_1'] == df_2['ph_id_2']],how='left_anti')
```

, and

```
df_new = df_1.filter(df_1['ph_id_1'] != df_2['ph_id_2'])
```

Both are giving same results, different from actual one.

Comment: Any reason for not trying `df_new = df_1.join(df_2,[df_1['ph_id_1'] == df_2['ph_id_2']],how='right_outer')`?

Comment: Tried that, not getting the correct output. 
Someone having alteryx experience, kindly help.

Comment: Please supply a picture of the config panel of your Join Tool.

Comment: @johnjps111 Added the picture, link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqk22.png

Comment: Can you also provide a small data sample that provides the differing results; both with the Alteryx result, and the pyspark result? (e.g. http://www.learnbymarketing.com/1100/pyspark-joins-by-example/ (or) https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/ are able to show differences with very small samples). This doesn't seem like it should be too hard to figure out.

Comment: Pretty sure you're after the equivalent of a right anti join here, which isn't a thing, can you change the datasets around to then do the left anti join?

Comment: @KaneG Tried that, but output doesn't seem to match. I ain't getting the alteryx equivalent of joins. In addition the dataset I am working is preety huge to give the example.